# Stored procedure always returns 1 instead of computed value of a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The purpose of this stored procedure is to check whether a record exists (by input parameter):

- if not, create it with default value 0 and return 0.
- if it does, then increment the last value by 1 and return new value

But no matter how I rearrange this, it always returns `1`, and not my computed value. Other operations are fine, records are properly created, values are properly incremented.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE ORD_SCHEMA.ORDER_NUMBER_INCREMENTER
@allocatedDate DATE
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @resultNumberValue int;
        DECLARE @currentNumberValue int;
        BEGIN TRANSACTION INCREMENTER_TRANSACTION
        BEGIN TRY
            SET @currentNumberValue = (SELECT NUMBER_VALUE 
                                      FROM ORD_SCHEMA.ORD_ORDER_NUMBER
                                      WHERE ALLOCATED_DATE = @allocatedDate);
                                     
            IF(@currentNumberValue IS NULL)
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO ORD_SCHEMA.ORD_ORDER_NUMBER (ALLOCATED_DATE, NUMBER_VALUE)
                    VALUES(@allocatedDate, 0);
                    SET @resultNumberValue = 0;
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE ORD_SCHEMA.ORD_ORDER_NUMBER
                    SET NUMBER_VALUE = NUMBER_VALUE + 1
                    WHERE ALLOCATED_DATE = @allocatedDate;
                    SET @resultNumberValue = @currentNumberValue + 1;
                END 
            COMMIT TRANSACTION INCREMENTER_TRANSACTION
            RETURN @resultNumberValue;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION INCREMENTER_TRANSACTION
        END CATCH
    END
```

Comment: `RETURN` is designed to return the success status of a procedure, `0` meaning "success" and anything else failure, not return other information. Use an `OUTPUT` parameter.

Comment: Also, careful with this type of design, the above would easily suffer from race conditions due to the lack of locking.

Comment: @Larnu Ok, thanks. Second question: will it suffer from race conditions, since all operations are executed within a transaction?

Comment: Yes, because your `SELECT` doesn't cause any locking, so 2 transactions could both get a value, and assign the **same** value to `@currentNumberValue`, then the `INSERT`/`UPDATE` would occur while the other would have to wait for the lock to be released, and then the other would do the same operation, with the same value of `@currentNumberValue`.

Comment: @Larnu: well - `SELECT` **does** put a "shared lock" on a row it reads - and hangs on to that shared lock for various amounts of time (depending on the isolation level). It's shared - so a second reader can also read - but it's still a lock (which e.g. prevents another user from putting an exclusive lock on that same row to update or delete it)....

Comment: True, my choice of wording was poor there, @marc_s , perhaps I should of said it doesn't cause "the kind of lock you want". Likely the OP will want a `ROWLOCK` and `UPDLOCK` for the `SELECT`.